# Is it possible to change number formats of 4 columns of a row based on a text value in that row for a range of rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm in a bad spot - any help pointing me in the right direction would be helpful and much appreciated.

I've created a Access process that copies an excel file and updates it with data from 2 record sets using Copy Recordset. The process now creates 39 workbooks by copying a 'template workbook' to a new file. Each workbook will contain at least one tab, but generally contain more, one workbook has over 20 tabs.

This is all done in Access. It copies the 'template' file and then runs a loop, and using Copy Recordset copies the 'template' worksheet to each tab.

After adding the tab, it loads the data from 2 record sets into the sheet. The 1st recordset loads one row of data - no problem. However the second loads multiple rows - which can vary in number.

This all works fine. The problem is formatting columns D through G. 
If Column C = Revenue, Cost or Gross Margin (GM) I want that row's columns D through G formatted as currency.
If Column C = GM% then I want columns D through G formatted as a percentage.
If column C = Hours I don't have to format it.

What I would like is to create a function that formats these columns/rows based on Column C value, when the workbook is opened. I know there is an event that fires when the workbook is opened, and I know I have looped through all of the tabs in a workbook, o I'd want to run that function for each tab.

There may be one other issue - I think I can fix that in Access, but the EAC column is being exported as text and it should numeric. Not sure right now if that's being exported as Text - or EXCEL sees it as text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have images - but it won't let me post them just yet. If they would help - let me know, I'll try to email them to you.

Bob

Comment: You should post code - always helps get responses.  Also, why not just run the formatting when you create the workbooks?  That seem like the easiest way to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a way to do it, I've included the code.

However there may be a better way - so I'm open to suggestions.

```
Public Sub FormatTaskRows()

Dim Sheet       As Object
Dim rngTasks    As Range
Dim rngFCells   As Range
Dim strTaskEnd  As String
Dim ix          As Integer


For Each Sheet In Sheets
    If Sheet.Name = "Template" Then
        Sheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Else
        Sheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Sheet.Activate
        strTaskEnd = Range("C44").End(xlDown).Address
        Set rngTasks = Range("$C$44:" & strTaskEnd)
        'For Each Row In rngTasks
        For ix = 1 To rngTasks.Rows.Count
            Sheet.Unprotect
             If rngTasks.Cells(ix) = "Revenue" Or rngTasks.Cells(ix) = "Cost" Or rngTasks.Cells(ix) = "Gross Margin (GM)" Then
                Set rngFCells = Range(ActiveSheet.Name & "!D" & ix + 43 & ":G" & ix + 43)
                rngFCells.Select
                Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
             Else
                If rngTasks.Cells(ix) = "GM%" Then
                    Set rngFCells = Range(ActiveSheet.Name & "!D" & ix + 43 & ":G" & ix + 43)
                    rngFCells.Select
                    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0000%"
                End If
             End If
            Sheet.Protect
        Next ix
    End If

Next
```

End Sub